# Don't see Crashlytics reports in Firebase console

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I have added firebase and Crashlytics to Android project, I have done all settings, I'm creating crash and expected to see crash report in the Firebase console in the Crashlytics tab, instead it continues to display set up screen to me. I made crash on release apk on real device.

[image]

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. Try enabling debug mode, do a build and run of your app and see if that helps: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash#enable_debug_mode

Comment: Hello @MikeBonnell ! It didn't help, I still see that setup screen.

Comment: In that case please reach out to Firebase support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `react-native-firebase` for the Crashlytics and reports didn't appear, I started to use `react-native-fabric` for Crashlytics and I was able to see reports immediately, I guess there are some problems with library `react-native-firebase`.

Comment: is this still true now?

Comment: @kingston Crashlytics from react-native-firebase works now fine for me! Fabric is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Once you reached to step 3 in firebase console (as shown in your image), just run your project again (not reload).
then firebase will detect crashlytics automatically.